# Weird sentence in the Content policy

Tags: bug, legal, policy

I found a weird sentence in the [content policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy):

> When your account is suspended, public access to content contributed under that account may be blocked or removed, and your account may be suspended or deleted at our discretion.

In other words, it says

> When your account is suspended [...] your account may be suspended

I think this is very confusing, if not just wrong. I think that the difference might be that suspended in the first part of the sentence means suspension in the non-SE sense, where it means suspension in the SE sense (i.e. the [penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)) in the second part of the sentence. But that doesn't make it less confusing.

Comment: This appears to be copy and paste from some pre-made template, e.g. this exact wording also appears [here](http://programming.com/privacy). So, it's not really SE fault directly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: SE took full and complete responsibility for it the moment they made it their official legal policy, no matter where the wording was plagiarised from.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to read this in a non-contradictory way.

> When your account is suspended, [...], and your account may be suspended [..] at our discretion.

It first details what happens when the account is suspended, then says that the account can be suspended at SE's discretion. Grammatically, the ", and" should be a semicolon or even a period.

So now not only is it confusing, it's also ambiguous as to who is reading it correctly. Definitely time to change it.

Comment: If this is the intent, a less ambiguous way to say it may be to swap the order: "Your account may be suspended or deleted at our discretion; if your account is suspended, ...".

Answer (score 2):

I agree as well. Though you might understand it in [@Scimonster's view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280398/278543), it still seems quite confusing to me. Maybe the sentence should be something more like this:

> When your account is suspended, public access to content contributed under that account may be blocked or removed, and the account may also be deleted at our discretion after several violations.

Basically, the sentence is telling you that after being suspended, your content may be blocked from the public or outright deleted. It also tells you that SE holds the right to delete the account after multiple violations. I suppose that part could be removed to due to instant deletion of spammers so it looks more like this:

> When your account is suspended, public access to content contributed under that account may be blocked or removed, and the account may also be deleted at our discretion.

or:

> When your account is suspended, public access to content contributed under that account may be blocked or removed, and the account is subject to deletion at our discretion.

It makes more sense, holds the main ideas of the sentence, and fixes that last part of the sentence to avoid unnecessary repetition and confusion.

Comment: Certainly not the first option; SE should be able to delete accounts after just one violation.